# Get duplicated lines in file

Tags: python

Working on file with thousands of line

trying to find which line is duplicated exactly ( 2 times )

```
from collections import Counter
with open('log.txt') as f:
    string = f.readlines()
    c = Counter(string)
    print c
```

it give me the result of all duplicated lines but i need to get the repeated line (2 times only)

Comment: Are you still using python 2? IF so, upgrade to 3 as 2 has been out of support for [months now](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/23/the-final-python-2-release-marks-the-end-of-an-era/).

Comment: Please describe exactly where you are stuck.  You have successfully read the file and counted how many times each line appears.  How is it that you are now confused about checking to see which of those line counts is exactly `2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing all the strings and not just the repeated ones, to print only the ones which are repeated twice, you can print the strings which have a count of two.

```
from collections import Counter
with open('log.txt') as f:
    string = f.readlines()
    c = Counter(string)
    for line, count in c.items():
        if count==2:
            print(line)
```

Comment: is it possible to find the line number of duplicated lines too ?

Answer (score 1):

The Counter Object also provides information about how often a line occurs.
You can filter it using e.g. list comprehension.
This will print all lines, that occur exactly two times in the file

```
with open('log.txt') as f:
    string = f.readlines()
    print([k for k,v in Counter(string).items() if v == 2])
```

If you want to have all repeated lines (lines duplicated two or more times)

```
with open('log.txt') as f:
    string = f.readlines()
    print([k for k,v in Counter(string).items() if v > 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) i.e.

```
from collections import Counter
with open('log.txt') as f:
    c = Counter(f)
    print(c.most_common(1))
```

This prints the Counter entry with the highest count.